# Splitting BigIntegers digits

Tags: java

I am trying to split a big integer's digits. Let me be a bit more specific. I am using the Fibonacci sequence to generate a big integer, now using this algorithm I need to loop until I find a BigInteger where the first 9 digits and the last 9 digits are pandigital. Only problem is the amount I have to loop is 300K (now that BigInteger is going to be so huge).

I have tried converting the BigInteger into a string, and then using "substring(begin, end)." But, that is so slow, it took nearly 28 minutes just to do 100K indexes.

There is a mathematical solution for this, but I am not completely sure what it is, if someone could lead me within the right direction much would be appreciated. Note: I am not asking for the answer directly, just a step towards finding the right answer.

Here is my code just in case you're wondering:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String...strings)
    {       
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fib(300_000);
        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Finished processing, time: " + (timeEnd - timeStart) + " milliseconds.");
    }

    public static BigInteger fib(int n)
    {
        BigInteger prev1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0), prev2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            BigInteger savePrev1 = prev1;
            prev1 = prev2;
            prev2 = savePrev1.add(prev2);
        }
        return prev1;
    }

    static BigInteger[] pows = new BigInteger[16];

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            pows[i] = BigInteger.TEN.pow(i);
        }
    }

    static boolean isPanDigital(BigInteger n) {
         if (!n.remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(9)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
           return false;
        }
        boolean[] foundDigits = new boolean[9];


        boolean isPanDigital = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            BigInteger digit = n.remainder(pows[i]).divide(pows[i - 1]);
            for (int j = 0; j < foundDigits.length; j++) {
                if (digit.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(j + 1)) && !foundDigits[j]) {
                    foundDigits[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            isPanDigital = isPanDigital && foundDigits[i];
        }

        return isPanDigital;
    }
}
```

Updated, managed to figure out how to generate the first 9 digits (and it doesn't seem to be too slow). But, I am having an issue generating the last 9 digits.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String...strings)
    {       
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fib(300_000);
        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Finished processing, time: " + (timeEnd - timeStart) + " milliseconds.");
    }

    public static BigInteger fib(int n)
    {
        BigInteger prev1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0), prev2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (prev1.toString().length() > 19)
            {
                String leading9Digits = leading9Digits(prev1);
                if (isPanDigital(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(leading9Digits))))
                {
                    System.out.println("Solved at index: " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            BigInteger savePrev1 = prev1;
            prev1 = prev2;
            prev2 = savePrev1.add(prev2);
        }
        return prev1;
    }

    public static String leading9Digits(BigInteger x) {
        int log10 = (x.bitLength() - 1) * 3 / 10;
        x = x.divide(BigInteger.TEN.pow(Math.max(log10 + 1 - 9, 0)));
        return x.toString().substring(0, 9);
    }

    static BigInteger[] pows = new BigInteger[16];

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            pows[i] = BigInteger.TEN.pow(i);
        }
    }

    static boolean isPanDigital(BigInteger n) {
         if (!n.remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(9)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
           return false;
        }
        boolean[] foundDigits = new boolean[9];


        boolean isPanDigital = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            BigInteger digit = n.remainder(pows[i]).divide(pows[i - 1]);
            for (int j = 0; j < foundDigits.length; j++) {
                if (digit.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(j + 1)) && !foundDigits[j]) {
                    foundDigits[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            isPanDigital = isPanDigital && foundDigits[i];
        }

        return isPanDigital;
    }
}
```

Comment: `But, that is so slow, ...` What is slow? String conversion itself? Taking of substring? Or calculation process?

Comment: The slow part is taking the substring of the BigInteger, since you're substringing such a huge number. It could possibly take up to 6 hours if I made it go up 300k

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand: `BigInteger.toString()` or `String.substring`. You need only 9 symbols it shouldn't take much time.

Comment: I'm not sure what are your requirements, but maybe you should take a look on [O(logN) fibonacci number calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form)

Comment: And dividing such a huge BigIntegers is certainly not a good idea.

Comment: The other problem is the version of the `Fibonacci` algorithm, you are using is also pretty ineffective, it should only take 1-2 seconds to get the 45,000th sequence (which is `2910856237598579040`).

Comment: This sounds exactly like Project Euler 104. If so, you have already passed the correct answer. As with all Euler problems there is a trick, maybe you don't need all the digits even while calculating?

Comment: Yeah, The thing that is taking such a long time is the `BigInteger.toString` not necessarily the `String.substring` (if you understand now.

Also, I will be sure to take a look at that.

Comment: I've checked it. AFAIU 30000th fibonacci has 62696 digits.

Comment: @Killrawr I don't understand what you're meaning, the way I am generating the Fibonacci is perfectly fine.

Comment: @defaultlocale Yea, now the problem is, I need a fast way to find the BigInteger where the first nine, and list nine digits are pandigital.

The answer is between index 0 - 300,000

Comment: @RogerLindsjö I've never heard of that, what is it?

Comment: String operations are much more efficient than BigInteger arithmetic. You definitely should use them to check "pandigitality" of a number.

Comment: I updated the main post, I've solved the first 9 (it doesn't seem _too_ slow). How would I go among getting the last 9 digits, in sorta the same way?

Comment: @ThomasLeGodais see http://projecteuler.net specifically http://projecteuler.net/problem=104

Comment: @ThomasLeGodais Remember, for large numbers, only the last digits affect the last digits of the sum. if you have two very large numbers that you want to add and only want the last 10 digits of the sum, then you only need to add the last 10 digits of the large numbers.

Comment: This seems more a mathematics problem than a programming problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. 

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I made a number of optimizations to your code.

- Your `leading9Digits` method should not return a `String`, it should return a number. Allow other parts of your code to turn it into a string if they prefer.
- Calling `BigInteger.pow()` every time the code loops is a waste. You can precalculate all these powers of 10 and store them in an array.
- You don't have to use an inner loop to check for pandigitalness. If you ever have to increment a cell in your `boolean` array twice, then it's not pandigital. Additionally, you can early exit on a `0`.
- Calculating `trailing9digits` is easy using [mod 1000000000](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Modulus.html)
- You can pre-create your constants and store them rather than creating them each time. Your way is fine for primitives but not objects.

Note, I tried using a `String` instead of remainders, they worked out to be about the same. I included both in your code.

And, finally, the correct answer is not in the first 300,000; it's about 329,000. And it takes about 29 seconds to run on my machine.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    private static final BigInteger NINE = BigInteger.valueOf(9);
    private static final BigInteger BILLION = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000000);
    private static final double log10_2 = Math.log10(2);
    private static final double CORRECTION = 9d;
    private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 131072;

    static BigInteger[] pows = new BigInteger[ARRAY_SIZE];

    static {
        pows[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 1; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            pows[i] = pows[i - 1].multiply(BigInteger.TEN);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... strings) {
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fib(500_000);
        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Finished processing, time: "
                + (timeEnd - timeStart) + " milliseconds.");
    }

    public static BigInteger fib(int n) {
        BigInteger prev1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0), prev2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (prev1.bitLength() > 30) {
                if (isDualPanDigital(prev1)) {
                    System.out.println("Solved at index: " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            BigInteger savePrev1 = prev1;
            prev1 = prev2;
            prev2 = savePrev1.add(prev2);
        }
        return prev1;
    }

    public static BigInteger leading9Digits(BigInteger x) {
        int dividePower = (int) (x.bitLength() * log10_2 - CORRECTION);
        BigInteger y = x.divide(pows[dividePower]);
        if (y.compareTo(BILLION) != -1) y = y.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        return y;
    }

    public static BigInteger trailing9Digits(BigInteger x) {
        return x.mod(BILLION);
    }

    static boolean isDualPanDigital(BigInteger n) {
        boolean leading = isPanDigital(leading9Digits(n));
        boolean trailing = isPanDigital(trailing9Digits(n));

        if (leading && trailing) {
            System.out.format("leadingDigits: %s, trailingDigits: %s%n",
                    leading9Digits(n), trailing9Digits(n));
        }
        return leading && trailing;
    }

    static boolean isPanDigital(BigInteger n) {
        if (!n.remainder(NINE).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            return false;
        }

        return isPanDigitalString(n);
    }

    private static boolean isPanDigitalMath(BigInteger n) {
        boolean[] foundDigits = new boolean[10];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            int digit = n.remainder(pows[i]).divide(pows[i - 1]).intValue();
            if (digit == 0)
                return false;
            if (foundDigits[digit - 1])
                return false;
            else
                foundDigits[digit - 1] = true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isPanDigitalString(BigInteger n) {
        boolean[] foundDigits = new boolean[9];

        String s = n.toString();
        if (s.length() < 9) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            int digit = s.charAt(i) - '1';
            if (digit == -1 || foundDigits[digit])
                return false;
            foundDigits[digit] = true;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```