# Cutting of the first 9 digits

Tags: java, algorithm, math, fibonacci

Alright I am trying to solve a challenge one of my friends gave me to do, well I've manged to cut the last 9 digits out of a `BigInteger` well I had a way to cut-off the first 9 but it was so slow, it was taking too long.

The reason I need the first 9 and the last 9 is because I am looking for a `BigInteger` where the first and last are pandigital.

If you do not understand what I mean say we have `n = new BigInteger("123456789987654321")` well I need to get the "123456789" and the "987654321" seperately, and I do **NOT** want to convert the BigInteger to a string because that's a VERY slow process.

I am going for speed here, I am just stumped on this solution. I've heard something about using the Golden Ratio? Here is my code if you're interested.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String...strings)
    {       
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fib(350_000);
        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Finished processing, time: " + (timeEnd - timeStart) + " milliseconds.");
    }

    public static BigInteger fib(int n)
    {
        BigInteger prev1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0), prev2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {   

            // TODO: Check if the head is pandigital as well.
            BigInteger tailing9Digits = tailing9Digits(prev1);
            boolean tailPandigital = isPanDigital(tailing9Digits);

            if (tailPandigital)
            {                   
                System.out.println("Solved at index: " + i);
                break;
            }
            BigInteger savePrev1 = prev1;
            prev1 = prev2;
            prev2 = savePrev1.add(prev2);
        }
        return prev1;
    }

    public static BigInteger leading9Digits(BigInteger x)
    {
        // STUCK HERE.
        return null;
    }

    public static BigInteger tailing9Digits(BigInteger x) 
    {
        return x.remainder(BigInteger.TEN.pow(9));
    }

    static BigInteger[] pows = new BigInteger[16];

    static 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
        {
            pows[i] = BigInteger.TEN.pow(i);
        }
    }

    static boolean isPanDigital(BigInteger n) 
    {
        if (!n.remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(9)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        boolean[] foundDigits = new boolean[9];


        boolean isPanDigital = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
        {
            BigInteger digit = n.remainder(pows[i]).divide(pows[i - 1]);
            for (int j = 0; j < foundDigits.length; j++) {
                if (digit.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(j + 1)) && !foundDigits[j])
                {
                    foundDigits[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            isPanDigital = isPanDigital && foundDigits[i];
        }

        return isPanDigital;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the quickest you have achieved and for what input?

Comment: Hi Thomas, if I understand correctly you want an efficient/fast algo to get the first 9 digits of a BigInteger? I would suggest you explicitly mention what you need some help on. Also, maybe include tags like algo, etc.

Comment: redoing your question from yesterday why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216777/splitting-bigintegers-digits

Comment: @SeanF The question from last time was about the tailing 9 digits.

Comment: @czarpino I couldn't really be more blunt, I'm just trying to get the first 9 digits of a `BigInteger` only problem is, converting it to a string, and doing `substring` is too slow, it could take up to 6 hours to be honest.

Comment: how about using modulo?

Comment: In order to determine if a number is pandigital in a given base you must express it in that base and examine the resulting string.  You _must_ convert it to string.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was a *mathematically meaningful* use-case that required you to get the leading N digits of a number with an unrelated length.  And for non-mathematical applications, you are probably using the wrong representation ... a String would be better than a BigInteger.

Comment: @Ardhian'koponk'Nugroho Using `x.mod(BigInteger.TEN.pow(9))` will return the last 9.

Comment: @JimGarrison You're incorrect, I do not need to use a `String` at all

@StephenC What are you talking about, elaborate more please?

Comment: @JimGarrison: No, you don't necessarily need to convert the whole thing to a string.

Comment: @tmyklebu Yeah, I'm not sure where he got that from, I'm trying to get around it.

I know it's possible to solve this issue using math.

Comment: x.mod(BigInteger.TEN.pow(9*a)) where a calculated from length of x, how?

Comment: @Ardhian'koponk'Nugroho: That'll be brutal, though, since you're calling `BigInteger.divide()`, which itself is brutal.

Answer (score 1):

`BigInteger` isn't something I'd recommend using if you care at all about speed.  Most of its methods are poorly-implemented, and this typically results in very slow code.

There's a divide-and-conquer trick for division and radix conversion that you might find helpful.

First, `BigInteger`'s `multiply()` is quadratic.  You'll need to work around that, otherwise these divide-and-conquer tricks won't lead to any speedup.  Multiplication via the fast Fourier transform is reasonably fast and good.

If you want to convert a `BigInteger` to base 10, break it in half (bitwise) and write it as `a * 256^k + b.`  One thing you can do is convert `a` and `b` to base-10 recursively, then convert `256^k` to decimal by repeated squaring, and then, in base 10, multiply `a` by `256^k` and add `b` to the result.  Also, since you're only interested in the first few digits, you might not even need to convert `b` if the first few digits of `a * 256^k` can't possibly be influenced by adding something as small as `b`.

A similar trick works for division.

You can do bit-shifting and extraction using the `toByteArray()` method.

Comment: Could you explain how I would go amongst getting the first 9 digits of a the `BigInteger` by shifting?

Comment: Maybe I was unclear.  You can use `toByteArray()` to break the number into its "top half" and its "bottom half" in the recursion.

Comment: I tried this: http://pastie.org/6409396 and the output looks like this: http://pastie.org/6409398. Could you explain how this could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not too fast but at least it's simple

```
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger("123456789987654321");
    BigInteger n2 = n.divide(BigInteger.TEN.pow(new BigDecimal(n).precision() - 9));
    BigInteger n1 = n.remainder(new BigInteger("1000000000"));
    System.out.println(n1);
    System.out.println(n2);
```

output

```
987654321
123456789
```

Comment: But he said that the number could be anything. It's not necessarily 18 digit long.

Comment: For an input of `1234567899987654321` I am getting `9987654321` and `123456789` as output. That's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe this is what you need:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class PandigitalCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger num = new BigInteger("12345678907438297438924239987654321");
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Is Pandigital: " + isPandigital(num));
        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (timeEnd - timeStart) + " ms");
    }

    private static boolean isPandigital(BigInteger num) {
        if (getTrailing9Digits(num).compareTo(getLeading9Digits(num)) == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static BigInteger getLeading9Digits(BigInteger num) {
        int length = getBigIntLength(num);
        BigInteger leading9 = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            BigInteger remainder = num.divide(BigInteger.TEN.pow(length - 1 - i));
            leading9 = leading9.add(remainder.multiply(BigInteger.TEN.pow(i)));
            num = num.remainder(BigInteger.TEN.pow(length - 1 - i));
        }

        return leading9;
    }

    private static int getBigIntLength(BigInteger num) {
        for (int i = 1; ; i++) {
            if (num.divide(BigInteger.TEN.pow(i)) == BigInteger.ZERO) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger getTrailing9Digits(BigInteger num) {
        return num.remainder(BigInteger.TEN.pow(9));
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Is Pandigital: true
Time Taken: 0 ms
```

Does it fit the bill?

Comment: Since I am running such a big loop I get an exception with negative exponent for: `BigInteger remainder = num.divide(BigInteger.TEN.pow(length - 1 - i));`

Comment: I know it's something to do with "- 1 - i" is there a way around this?

Comment: For what input are you getting this error? If it's too large to post here you can use pastebin.com.

Comment: It's because the first 2 numbers of the fibonacci sequence are 0.

Comment: I didn't get you. How did fibonacci sequence come into play? If you could just provide the input you are giving then maybe I can debug my code.

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you are doing in the `fib` method. You are setting `prev1` to 0 and `prev2` to 1. These are just 1 digit numbers. Where does the large `BigInteger`, which you want to check is pandigital, come into play?

Comment: Read it more clearer, http://pastie.org/6409676#26-28,30 That should explain what it does, it's not set to zero and 1 each time.

Answer (score 0):

I’m newbie for java, I’m converting BigInteger to String only but it's little bit fast as your code

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {       
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String biStr = new BigInteger("123456789987654321").toString();
        int length=(biStr.length())/2;
        String[] ints = new String[length];
        String[] ints2 = new String[length];
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            int j=i+length;
            ints[i] = String.valueOf(biStr.charAt(i));
            ints2[i] = String.valueOf(biStr.charAt(j));
            System.out.println(ints[i] +"  |  "+ints2[i]);
        }
        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Finished processing, time: " + (timeEnd - timeStart) + " milliseconds.");
    }
}
```